# Flutter Firebase Pagination - Nested Query

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, pagination, nested-loops

I am relatively new to the Flutter world and need some help in efficiently querying a nested Firebase query with pagination in Flutter.

I am building an app where I have a few thousand of user selected documents in collectionA (selected from >100k documents from collectionB) and  need to loop through a chunk of 10 documents (whereIn limit of 10) queried via stream. My current implementation (snippet below) takes a list of document ID's "d" and chunks in a list of 10 via quiver/iterables. The drawback of the methodology is that it reads thousands of user documents upfront before displaying it in the app. I would like to use a pagination and control the reads.

Would you suggest a solution (with a code snippet) on how to use the pagination through thousands of user selected documents?

```
Future<List<Article>> fbWhereGT10Article(
    String collection, String field, List<dynamic> d) async {
  final chunks = partition(d, 10);
  // print(chunks);
  final querySnapshots = await Future.wait(chunks.map(
    (chunk) {
      Query itemsQuery = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection(collection)
          .where(field, whereIn: chunk);
      // .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true);
      return itemsQuery.get();
    },
  ).toList());
  return querySnapshots == null
      ? []
      : await Stream.fromIterable(querySnapshots)
          .flatMap((qs) =>
              Stream.fromIterable(qs.docs).map((e) => Article.fromFirestore(e)))
          .toList();
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution, I am looking for this too?